# Examples of curvature-adapted subgroups of semi-Riemannian groups

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $G$ be a semi-Riemannian group, i.e., a Lie group equipped with a bi-invariant semi-Riemannian metric. I am looking for examples of Lie subgroups that are *curvature adapted to $G$*.

First, allow me to recall the definition of curvature-adapted submanifold.

Let $Q$ be a semi-Riemannian manifold, and let $M$ be a semi-Riemannian submanifold of $Q$. For any unit normal vector $\eta$ of $M$ at $p$, we define the *normal Jacobi operator of $M$ with respect to $\eta$* by
\begin{align*}K_{\eta} \colon T_{p}M &\to T_{p}Q\\
x &\mapsto R(\eta, x)\eta,
\end{align*}
where $R$ is the curvature tensor of $Q$. One says that $M$ is *curvature adapted to $Q$ at $p \in M$* if, for every $\eta \in N_{p}M$, the normal Jacobi operator $K_{\eta}$ preserves $T_{p}M$ and commutes with the corresponding shape operator $A_{\eta}$. Recall that the *shape operator of $M$ with respect to $\eta$* is the map
\begin{align*}A_{\eta} \colon T_{p}M &\to T_{p}M\\
x &\mapsto \pi^{\top} \nabla_{x}N, 
\end{align*}
where $N$ is an arbitrary (local) normal vector field along $M$ such that $N_{p} = \eta$. Consequently, one calls $M$ a *curvature-adapted submanifold* if it is curvature adapted at all points $p\in M$.

Now, in arbitrary codimension and in the case where $Q = G$, the simplest curvature-adapted submanifolds are the Lie subgroups $H$ of $G$ such that $K_{\eta}(T_{p}H)\subset T_{p}H$ for all normal vectors $(p, \eta)$ of $H$.

**Question**. Does anyone know how to find examples of these?

In fact, it is possible to prove that, if the normal bundle of $M \subset G$ is *abelian* (= each normal space of $M$ is tangent to a totally geodesic, flat submanifold of $Q$), then the condition $K_{\eta}(T_{p}M)\subset T_{p}M$ is automatic. Hence, any Lie subgroup with abelian normal bundle would make an example. (I have previously asked about submanifolds of $G$ with abelian normal bundle; see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/402821/74033).)

*Remark*. In dimension three, since a semi-Riemannian group has constant curvature, every submanifold is curvature adapted. Thus my question makes sense only in higher dimensions.